# Graphing a colored grid in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a 2D plot in python where the horizontal axis is split into a number of intervals or columns and the color of each column varies along the vertical axis.

The color of each interval depends on the value of a periodic function of time. For simplicity, let's say these values range between 0 and 1. Then values closer to 1 should be dark red and values close to 0 should be dark blue for example (the actual colors don't really matter).

Here is an example of what the plot should look like:

[image: Example of plot]

Is there a way to do this in Python using matplotlib?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html

Comment: That isn't particularly helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really just displaying an image. You can do this with `imshow`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

# Just some example data (random)
data = np.random.rand(10,5)

rows,cols = data.shape

plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', 
                 extent=[0.5, 0.5+cols, 0.5, 0.5+rows],
                 cmap='bwr')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go, will it automatically know what color to make the values?

Comment: @Daniel I just updated it with the `cmap` option which will map your data values to colors.

Comment: The only issue is that the vertical axis remains fixed, could I increase its size somehow?

Comment: @Daniel I just updated the `extent` input to be based upon the size of the input. Is that what you mean?